# Remove tags of POS tagger

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

Is it possible to remove the tags from the sentences? One can accomplish it by scanning through the file and finding tags and removing them, but since there are many tags( some models have 30+, some have around 48-50, they basically follow the [penn treebank pos tags](http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=penn+treebank+pos+tags&oq=penn+treebank+pos+tags&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=90l3139l0l3312l22l15l0l2l2l1l592l3727l0.4.1.3.0.3l11l0&gs_l=hp.3..0.90l3139l0l3313l22l15l0l2l2l1l592l3727l0j4j1j3j0j3l11l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b1609e7f0f1800b7&biw=1366&bih=601) ), is there a fast and sweet way to remove tags in a more efficient manner?
I did check the API, but there was no such method for removal of tags.

Comment: Can you explain with an example what you want?  If you just don't want POS tags, you don't run a POS tagger....

Comment: Suppose I tagged a file using the tagger, now I want to apply certain conditions on the file,based on the tags that appear next to each word. And after that,in the altered file,I obviously wouldn't want the tags to appear,they won't be useful at all,and disliked by the user. So, I would like to remove the tags.

I have found a work around for this,it isn't as simple a method as I've just explained above,I'll have to scan each line from the original document and from the tagged document simultaneously to achieve it.But I was just curious that is there a simpler way of removing the tags. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special built in for this, but since the output includes both the word and its tag, I'm not sure why you need to scan the original document again.  Can't you just delete the tags by deleting from the last tagSeparator character ('/' or whatever) until white-space?  Or, it could be simpler to use

```
-outputFormat tsv
```

Then you will get two column output with the words in the first column and the tag in the second column and you could just keep the first column when done.