# JAVA Separate the a sentence contains Part of Speech(POS) tag into free of POS tag sentence and just POS tag sentence?

Tags: java, string, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

Assume the sentences is:

> It/pps urged/vbd that/cs the/at next/ap Legislature/nn-tl `/` provide/vb enabling/vbg funds/nns and/cc re-set/vb the/at effective/jj date/nn so/cs that/cs an/at orderly/jj implementation/nn of/in the/at law/nn may/md be/be effected/vbn ''/'' ./.

The sentence above is take from brown corpus. How can I get the sentence free of all these POS tag and print and another sentence is just POS tag.

The sentence free of POS tag result like as below:

> It urged that the next Legislature `` provide enabling funds and re-set the effective date so that an orderly implementation of the law may be effected '' .

The sentence just POS tag result like as below:

> pps vbd cs at ap nn-tl `` vb vbg nns cc vb at jj nn cs cs at jj nn in at nn md be vbn '' .

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699674/remove-tags-of-pos-tagger :-)

Comment: is there any code or example to show to me.thank you.

Comment: That answer on that post says it all mate.

Comment: Besides, why are you going for such a hectic way? Simply keep track of each corresponding sentence of the original text with respect to the tagged text, things will be easier then.

Comment: Can you provide some code for me to review? Because I not really understand what means inside that post. I just need to take of the tag if possible, because I am using another POS tag that is not same as brown corpus.